Find the lenght of segment $AE$ in the figure below
In the figure, $BC = 3$m and $CD = 1$m.
Calculate $AE$.
(Answer: $\sqrt6$)

I try:
$\triangle ABF: BF^2 = AB^2+AF^2 = AB^2+(2r+AE)^2$
$\triangle EFC: (2r)^2=EC^2+CF^2$
$AC.AH = AE.(AE+2r)$
$\triangle OAF:OF^2 =R^2+(2r+AE)^2$

Can we assume $H$ is on the circumference of the smaller circle and $O_1H$ is vertical?

@YNK $H$ is on the  circunference. but we can't assume $O_1H$ is vertical

@YNK By geogebra $O_1$is perpendicular to $H$ but it would need to be demonstrated

We can show that. Let $\angle BFA = \alpha$, $\angle FEH = \beta$ and $\angle FAH = \theta$. Note that $\alpha + \theta = \beta$. Consider the segment $[O O_1]$, you can show that $2\alpha + 2\theta = 90^{\circ}$ in the right triangle $\triangle O O_1 A$ arising from the tangent angles, which gives $\beta = 45^{\circ}$. Then $\triangle EHO_1$ is an isosceles right triangle and $O_1 H$ is vertical.

Is this a duplicate of your earlier question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4935379/find-the-segment-ae-given-the-two-circles-below

@RobinSparrow Yes but I already deleted it


In figure the radii of circles $O$ and $O_1$ are equal. $AOHO_1$ is a rectangle. C is the mid point of AH and $EG\bot BF$. In the right angled triangle BGD we have:
$GC=\sqrt{3\times 1}=\sqrt 3$
$tan GBC=\frac{\sqrt 3}3=tan 30^o\Rightarrow \angle GBC=30^o$
$\angle GBC=\angle EBC=30 \Rightarrow EBG=60^o$
that is triangle BEG is equilateral and we have:
$ BE=BG=2\sqrt3$
In the right angle triangle ABE we have:
$AB=AE\Rightarrow \angle AEB=45^o$
Finally :
$AE=BE cos 45^o=2\sqrt 3\times \frac {\sqrt2}2=\sqrt6$
Update: Reason for $GE\bot BF$:As can be seen in the figure below:
$\triangle H_1DB=\triangle NCF\Rightarrow BD=NC$
$\triangle MGH=\triangle MAE\Rightarrow AE=GH$
Similarly $DG=EC$
These are possible only if $GE\bot H_1F$. In fact these are resulting from the rotation of the construction $GE\botH_1$ about point M(C in first figure)from its horizontal position.


Excellent..thnka fot help

How did you deduce that the radii are equal?

I don't understand $GC = \sqrt{3.1}$. I have only $BC$ in the $triangle BCG$

@petaarantes, In any right angle triangle the square of hight is equal to the product of the segments the foot of height makes. So $GC^2=BC\times CD=3\times 1=3$. This is in fact a particular case where radii are  equal and he construction is consistent such that you can deduce $EG\bot BF$ which is competent with the fact that points B, E, G and D are concyclic. The solution for unequal radii is also correct.+1

So you used the $\triangle BGD$  and not the $BGC$.

You used straight $\triangle BGD$ but I didn't see how you came to that conclusion. You drew the circle BGDE but I didn't understand how you guaranteed that it would pass through these points, as there is only the drawing

@petaarantes Yes I used triangle BGD. I will try to explain the reasons later.

Grateful for the attention


Continue with the part I mentioned in the comment.
Let $\angle BFA = \alpha$, $\angle FEH = \beta$, $\angle FAH = \theta$; given $\alpha + \theta = \beta$, $\angle OO_1A = 90^\circ$ in $\triangle OO_1A$ with $\angle OAO_1 = 2\alpha$, $\angle O_1AO = 2\theta$, hence $2\alpha + 2\theta = 90^\circ$, yielding $\alpha + \theta = 45^\circ$, thus $\beta = 45^\circ$, making $\triangle EHO_1$ isosceles right, implying $O_1H$ vertical.
Given $[EC] \perp [BF]$ and $[EA] \perp [AO]$, we can see that the quadrilateral $BCEA$ is cyclic.
Drawing the segment $[BE]$, we have the equal angles $\angle EAC = \angle EBC = \angle HEC = \theta$.
In $\triangle EBC$ and $\triangle ECD$, the tangent of the angle $\theta$:
$$
\tan{\theta} = \frac{EC}{\Omega_1} = \frac{\Omega_2}{EC} \implies EC = \sqrt{\Omega_1 \Omega_2}.
$$
So it is simply $\triangle CEH \sim \triangle EAH$:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\Omega_1 \Omega_2}}{x} = \frac{b}{r\sqrt{2}}
$$
and $\triangle CEH \sim \triangle EBF$:
$$
\frac{b}{2r} = \frac{\Omega_1 \Omega_2}{\sqrt{{\Omega_1}^2 + \Omega_1 \Omega_2}}
$$
We deduce that $$\therefore x=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\Omega_1^2 + \Omega_1 \Omega_2}}{2} = \sqrt{6}.$$
